# How to point a structure to a particluar address

Tags: c, struct, structure, typedef

I am trying to point a structure to a particular memory location , can anyone please tell me how it can be done in c programming . 
I have defined a macro which holds the starting address of the memory location.

```
#define START_ADDR 0xF6000 //starting address

typedef struct {
     uint32_t checksum;
     uint16_t index[len];
} block;
```

I changed the memory allocation of block using the below statement:

```
block *value = (block*) START__ADDR;
```

I verified the change in memory allocation as well and no issue with it.I am working on FLASH memory and i have verified that writing operation can be done on the particular memory location which i have mentioned.
Now i am trying to update the value of checksum using

```
value->checksum=0xa5a5a5a5;
```

But the value of checksum is **0x00000000** and not getting updated to **0xa5a5a5a5**.
Can anyone please tell me how can i change the value of checksum.

Thanks in advance.

Regards 
Vybhav

Comment: I am not sure of what you are trying to do. Why do you need this structure to point at this address ?
Do you own this address ? Unless you are writing code for a very specific case (a kernel, embedded), you probably don't have the right to access to an arbitrary address.

Comment: This is implementation-specific. What C compiler are you using?

Comment: Did you mean you want your structure variable to begin with that address? If yes, you can create a pointer variable to the structure and assign the address to that variable. i.e. block *block_addr = (block *) START_ADDR;

Comment: block here is a type. You would need to have an instance of this type to point to the desired address

Comment: @MayurK ,this is what i was looking for . Thanks

Comment: @MayurK , I am trying to access the structure elements but i am not able to update its value using the below command.                                    
block_addr->checksum=0xXXXXX                                                can you please tell me how to update the structure elements.

Comment: @VybhavJayaraman I am not sure about what are you trying to do. Do you know what memory is it? Writing is allowed at that address on your platform? May be it is better if you can update your question with more details now.

Comment: @MayurK,i am using flash memory and writing is allowed at that address. Sure i will update.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you do know what you are setting or landing there (and you have permissions to do that), two main ways are:

a) Derefering a pointer which points to the address:

```
#define ADDR 0xXXXXXX
unsigned int volatile * const var = (unsigned int *) ADDR;
```

Your specific case:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t checksum;
    uint16_t index[len];
} block_t;

unsigned block_t volatile * const block = (block_t *) ADDR;
block->checksum = 0;
```

b) Through the linker:

file.c:

```
block_t __attribute__((section(".theSection"))) block;
block.checksum = 0;
```

linker.ld:

```
SECTIONS
{
    .theSegment 0xXXXXXX : {KEEP(*(.theSection))}
}
```

*Note that I have renamed the type `block` to `block_t`.*

Comment: Will structure padding affect in this case? Shouldn't it be a packed structure?

Comment: @Swanand It may affect, but the aim of the question is to place a struct in a specific address. However, I don't know if padding or unaligned accesses are allowed (or not).

Comment: IMPO, if that matters, I would use architecturally defined types

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the address to a pointer to a `struct block` object. Also you need an instance of a `struct block` object to assign the casted pointer.

See this example:

```
struct block * volatile block_pointer = (struct block*)START_ADDR;
```